# Are there any differences between an inverting opamp with gain X vs. a voltage divider with gain X followed by buffer?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, adc, single-supply-op-amp

I'm looking for the advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other, especially for low-noise applications where I'll be feeding the output into an ADC.

In terms of AC response, the BW looks the same, the only thing different is the phase.

In terms of real-world applications, does having a virtual ground help with noise in any way?

Now I know the inverting will change phase

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156101/best-topology-for-active-attenuator   ??

Comment: This question makes no sense considering that the AD8601 isn't particularly any great saviour when it comes to noise. Much more information needed to avoid this being a question that only solicits opinions.

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/industry-articles/how-to-reduce-noise-in-low-voltage-amplifier-designs/

Comment: http://dicks-website.eu/noisecalculator/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Several differences:

- The U2 version inverts the signal polarity The circuit is known as inverting amp.
- Different gains. The voltage divider version outputs V1(R2)/(R1+R2) the inverting amp outputs -(V1)(R4)/R3
- Load differently the signal source The voltage divider is approximately  like R1+R2, the inverting amp is like R3.
- Different noise performance and maybe stability problems in practical low gain (=actually attenuating) inverting amp, but these things are complex. They belong to advanced design and are beyond the scope of this answer.

About virtual ground: It's the name of the minus signal input node of the opamp when its used as inverting amp. The opamp tries to output just that output voltage which through the resistor balances the input voltage at minus input to 0V ; that's the same as the GND. You have no way to add virtual GND to the upper version. The whole concept belongs only to the cases where opamp works in its linear range, its plus signal input is connected to GND and both the feedback from the output and the feeding the signal or several signals happen through resistors or other parts only to the minus input.

Comment: thanks for the response. What I was asking about is noise performance and stability problems, since I'm looking to drop +/-500V to values between -1.25V and 1.25V.

This means that I need a gain of around 2.5e-3. Where can I run into problems with this attenuation factor?

Comment: Use the voltage divider version. It has no stability problems as long as the opamp is guaranteed to be stable at unity gain. Read something of "the frequency compensation of opamps" To 100% understand it quantitatively you must be familiar with Laplace transforms and frequency domain stability theory in feedback control systems (opamp amplifiers are such things). Noise is not your problem. Opamps generate noise maybe microvolts and nanoamperes. You can very likely to have low enough R2 resistance.